# Table from array using range(len()) in Jinja2

Tags: html, html-table, jinja2

Im trying to create a table using html and Jinja2. The problem I'm facing is that I need to split each index of my list. (Example of list: [('Jessy  Peterson')('Harry  James')]). At the moment this is the code I'm working with:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            {% for choice in choices %}
                <th><b>{{choice}}</b></th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for choice in choices %}
                    {​​​​​​​% for i in range(0, test| length) %}​​​​​​
                       {% set h = output[i].split("  ") %}
                        <td>{{output[h]}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When opening the application I get an error:
**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endfor'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.**

Since looping in python is really inconvenient in this script I want to do it with jinja. My question is, how do I correctly get the length of the array in the loop: *{​​​​​​​% for i in range(0, test| length) %}​​​​​​*?

Full template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Uniprot DB{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Blast</h1>
    <!--    -->
    <script src='static/java.js'></script>
    <h2>Background information</h2>
    <p id="background" hidden>Dit is de achtergrond informatie</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('background').style.display='none'">Hide me!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('background').style.display='block'">Show me!</button>

    <!--    -->
    <h2>Checklist</h2>
    <p>Check what you want to see</p>

    <!--  Checkbox for the parameters  -->
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_organisme" name="blast_organisme" value="organisme">
    <label for="blast_organisme">organisme</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_description" name="blast_description" value="description">
    <label for="blast_description">description</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_e_value" name="blast_e_value" value="e_value">
    <label for="blast_e_value">e_value</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_query_cover" name="blast_query_cover" value="query_cover">
    <label for="blast_query_cover">query_cover</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_per_ident" name="blast_per_ident" value="per_ident">
    <label for="blast_per_ident">per_ident</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_acc" name="blast_acc" value="accessiecode">
    <label for="blast_acc">blast_acc</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="taxonomie" name="taxonomie" value="tax_name">
    <label for="blast_acc">taxonomie</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sequentie" name="sequentie" value="sequentie">
    <label for="blast_acc">sequentie</label><br>

     <!--  Text input: organism/protein name  -->
     <p>Give organism name:</p>
     <input type="text" name="answer">

    <!--  Search choise: protein or organism name  -->
    <div id="wrapper">
    <label for="protein or organism">organism or protein</label>
    <input type="radio" name="org_pro" value="tax_name" checked>organism</input>
    <input type="radio" name="org_pro" value="description">protein</input>
    <input type="radio" name="org_pro" value="header">header</input>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <!--<h4>How can I find the protein?</h4>-->
    <p id="uitleg" hidden>If you chose the parameter description you can see the protein after the
    accesioncode and before the organism name shown in brackets. Example of an accessioncode: ref|WP_162409790.1|</p>
    <!--<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('uitleg').style.display='none'">Hide me!</button>-->
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('uitleg').style.display='block'">How can I find the protein?</button>

    <!--  Output query  -->
<!--    <p>Uw zoekwoord: {{answer}}</p>-->
<!--    {% for x in test %}-->
<!--    <li>{{x}}</li>-->
<!--    {% endfor %}-->
<!--    <br>-->


    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            {% for choice in choices %}
                <th><b>{{choice}}</b></th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for choice in choices %}
                    {​​​​​​​% for i in range(0, test| length) %}​​​​​​
                        <p>test</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--  Output query  -->
{% endblock %}
```

**Base**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you want to get the value of `output[i]` and feed that split back into `output` just a thought? Also why not try putting a placeholder text "test" before `{% set h = ...`  and remove that and the `<td>` element. Just so see where the error is.   Also have you got a block anywhere in there thats throwing you off. Maybe this code is fine (looks ok to me without testing.)

Comment: I just removed the {% set h = ...  and replaced <td>... with a <p>test</p>. Still got the same error though. I sweeped the code again and didn't spot any missplaced blocks. When running the program I still get the same error.

Comment: Please paste the full template.